# What is the command for executing a T-SQL procedure by passing an input value and take an out put value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Sorry to ask this simple question, I am new to T-SQL

What is the command for executing a T-SQL stored procedure by passing an input value and take an output value?

Say for example there are 2 variables like `@id` (input) and `@sal` (output)

Requirement is to pass the id and get salary. So do we need to execute like this?

```
EXEC USP_PROC1 89, 0
```

(*DO I NEED TO PASS THE OUTPUT VARIABLES' DEFAULT VALUE AS WELL*)

When I executed it why can not I see any answer? I can only see `Command(s) completed successfully`.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN is your friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx). It has tons of examples for you, on top of the basic syntax layout.

[Here is another site with some examples.](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_&_Return_Values)

```
EXEC USP_PROC1 89,0, @OutputValue OUTPUT
```

Comment: let me know what i have to do to see the out put

Comment: @user1254579 you can `PRINT @OutputValue` or `SELECT @OutputValue` or whatever you would normally do with a variable...think of it like `Out` in C# if you are familiar